# common between all csv columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file.

```
table1    table2    table3  table4   table5
paper     paper     pen     book     book
pen       pencil    pencil  charger  apple
apple     pen       charger beatroot sandle
beatroot  mobile    apple   pen      paper
sandle    book      paper   paper
```

I need to find similar entries among all columns. In this case output will be :

```
paper
```

It may happen that columns may increase or decrease.

For 2 column similarities can be done using :

```
# reading csv file and converting it to dictionary
with open(input_file, 'r') as csvin:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvin)
    data={k.strip():[v] for k,v in reader.next().items()}
    for line in reader:
        for k,v in line.items():
            k=k.strip()
            data[k].append(v)

# iterating the dictionary for each 2 columns
for a, b in itertools.combinations(data, 2):
    # to get common species names
    common = set(data[a]) & set(data[b])
```

But, I do not understand how to get similar values from all columns.

Comment: Check out `DictReader` and `sets`.

Comment: What research have you done? What code have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with [`skipinitialspace=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to skip the spaces, then zip the rows to get the columns, we use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) because a value in the last column is missing. Convert the columns in set and take the intersection using [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv

with open('test') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    cols = map(set, izip_longest(*reader))

print set.intersection(*cols)
```

Watch out that your file is not properly a csv, and if you have missing values in a column that is not the last one this will interpret your input not properly. Consider at least using a delimiter that is not space.

## Example

Using [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to parse a string and show that it works for the test case:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv
import StringIO

data='''table1    table2    table3  table4   table5
paper     paper     pen     book     book
pen       pencil    pencil  charger  apple
apple     pen       charger beatroot sandle
beatroot  mobile    apple   pen      paper
sandle    book      paper   paper'''

f = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
cols = map(set, izip_longest(*reader))

print set.intersection(*cols)
```

*Output*

```
set(['paper'])
```

Comment: Mmm. it works for me. it match `paper` and I'm using your example file.

Comment: yes I am testing the same. It prints all the values and not common

Comment: Check the example so we can figure out what's the difference between the output I get and the one you get.